# Exception in String.Format vc++

Tags: string, visual-c++, mfc

```
CString serror;
sError.Format( _T("Order Id- %d :CPVAudit could not audit event name: Medication Administration, and event type: %s"), dParticipantId, sEventType);
```

This code is throwing an access violation exception. The variables dParticipantId(double), sEventType(CString) are getting populated with the correct values but still this line is throwing an exception.

Comment: variable `serror` and `sError` are not similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if dParticipantId is a double, you're using the wrong [type specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx).  Try something like '%f' instead.  Otherwise, make dParticipantId an integer.